# EclipseLink Errors during persistance to Postgres

Tags: jpa, jboss, eclipselink, wildfly

I have 3 entities which i want to ganerate them to table in PostgreSql using JPA and EclipseLink, between these classes there is relaltions and i doubt  that there is a lack of jar file in my project:

This is the first Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUPE", catalog = "", schema = "SYNCPKTME")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Groupe.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM Groupe g")})
public class Groupe implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "IDGROUPE")
    private BigDecimal idgroupe;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "NOMGROUPE")
    private String nomgroupe;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "LIBELLE")
    private String libelle;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "CREE_PAR")
    private String creePar;
    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATION")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateCreation;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "MAJ_PAR")
    private String majPar;
    @Column(name = "DATE_MAJ")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateMaj;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idgroupe")
    private List<PersonneGroupe> personneGroupeList;

    public Groupe() {
    }....
```

This is the second Class : PERSON

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "PERSONNE", schema = "SYNCPKTME")
    public class Personne implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "IDPERSONNE")
        private BigDecimal idpersonne;
        @Size(max = 10)
        @Column(name = "MATRICULE")
        private String matricule;
        @Size(max = 45)
        @Column(name = "NOM")
        private String nom;
        @Size(max = 45)
        @Column(name = "PRENOM")
        private String prenom;
        @Size(max = 45)
        @Column(name = "UTILISATEUR")
        private String utilisateur;
        @Size(max = 10)
        @Column(name = "CREE_PAR")
        private String creePar;
        @Column(name = "DATE_CREATION")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date dateCreation;
        @Size(max = 45)
        @Column(name = "MAJ_PAR")
        private String majPar;
        @Column(name = "DATE_MAJ")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date dateMaj;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idpersonne")
        private List<PersonneGroupe> personneGroupeList;....
```

[image]

These are errors due to JPA TOOL when i'm trying to generate tables from entities , i really need ur help knowing that i'm new in this field.

Comment: and at the foot of that exception you will find the root cause ... something is not in the CLASSPATH that needs to be

Comment: @DNA1 could you explain to me plz =) !!!?

Comment: You post some exception with part of the stack trace. Post the whole thing including the last part, the root cause. This is basic Java

Comment: you don't have EclipseLink jars in your class path that you are showing, and the exception mentions an EclipseLink class can't be found